# Point free style in haskell

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I'm trying to change

```
function (x:xs) = unwords (map reverse (words (x:xs)))
```

into point free style, and I can't do this.

isn't it simply

```
function = unwords . map . reverse . words
```

Please help me to change this to point free style.

I tried to use pointfree after doing below command line

```
cabal install pointfree
```

Everything compiled and installed but when I type pointfree in terminal, it's keep saying there's no such thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your definition is almost correct and can be tested in ghci interpreter, it should be

```
ghci> let function = unwords . map reverse . words
ghci> function "The quick brown fox"
"ehT kciuq nworb xof"
```

because `reverse` is an argument of map. Basically, to change pipeline-like function `foo a3 = f a1 (g a2 (h a3))` (consisting of nested function calls) into pointfree, where the explicit argument (`a3` in this case) is the last called, you need to remove it and replace nested parentheses with `.` composition operator: `foo = f a1 . g a2 . h`. However, this trick doesn't work when there are multiple arguments or the argument is used more than once. To meaningly operate with pointfree functions, you should understand 
[combinatory logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic).

EDIT: oh, I got that you tried to use [the command-line *pointfree* tool](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree) to auto-transform the function. Binaries compiled with cabal are placed in specific directory (for example, C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin in Windows, AFAIR) which is probably isn't added to PATH by default and so command line interpreter can't find the executable.

Answer (score 2):

`reverse` is an argument of `map`, so you don't have to compose `map` with `reverse`, but you want to compose the full `map reverse` with the other functions.

The correct way to do so is:

```
function = unwords . map reverse . words
```